# Get the id of SVG element that was being dragged

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I am using **svg.js** and **dragg.js** to move around a series of dynamically created objects (rects and circles etc).
They are all in a group called `nodes`, I can get the positioning of the item being dragged but I am lost at trying to retrieve the

g `id="dyanmicidIcreated"`

I need this to identify which SVG object was moved?

```
nodes.mouseup(node => {
  console.log("x: "+node.clientX)
  console.log("y: "+node.clientY)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console.log(SVG.adopt(event.target.parentNode).id())

Answer (score 2):

You pass a handler to the function which is called with the event which was fired.
So all information about the event is in the event object (which you for some reason called `node`).

```
nodes.mouseup((event) => {
    // mouse coordinates
    console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY)

    // the node which was clicked
    console.log(event.target)

    // the svgjs object
    console.log(SVG.adopt(event.target))

    // the id
    console.log(SVG.adopt(event.target).id())
})
```

If you dont use arrow functions, the function is called in the scope of the svgjs object. So you can just use `this`:

```
nodes.mouseup(function (event) {
    // `this` is same as node
    console.log(this)

    // id
    console.log(this.id())
})
```

In svg.js v3.0 you would use `SVG(event.target)` instead of `SVG.adopt`. Everything else stays the same

Comment: Thank you so much - this gets the tspan id of the node I need the id of the group it belongs to see image - i get SvgjsTspan1056  which is 10x better than before but I need yqgn8zzzyvashpr66jny5 ...https://www.dropbox.com/s/m12c9anbk5t3c9q/Screenshot%202019-01-05%2019.26.23.png?dl=0

Comment: Well what stops you from calling `graoupVar.id()`? Or `parent()`?

Comment: parent() I was not able to get the right thing.. here is the full code (might help) please excuse the mess - https://gitlab.adamprocter.co.uk/adamprocter/nodenoggin/blob/sharedlocations/src/components/user-interface.vue

Comment: Dude, `nodes.id()`. I am not sure what's so hard about that.

Comment: that just outputs the same ID for every drag not the one you dragged and is not the group ID i need unfortunately.  for example with that every one I drag outputs console.log(nodes.id())  as SvgjsG1015  :(

Comment: Guess you need to output the correct vars then. If target is a tspan, try originalTarget or use the Dom traversing methods like parent and children to get where you want. This is all no magic. Your question is also not clear about where the event is bound and what contains what.

Comment: I just want to grab the ID of the group no matter which element you pick up

Comment: What is `nodes`?

Comment: nodes is a group of SVG objects being created from info in a couchDB